# UITextField border-bottom will not be displayed fully

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, border

I am new to the `Swift`, and I want to add the border-bottom to the `UITextField` (Full border to the `UITextField's` width). I search the internet and I found lots of the code but they are not functional as I wanted.

My needs: I want that the border-bottom is set to be the full width of the `UITextField`.

Output Image link: [Chopped Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdwix.png)

```
let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(0.5)
border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(1).cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: firstName.frame.size.height - width, width:  firstName.frame.size.width, height: firstName.frame.size.height)

border.borderWidth = width
firstName.layer.addSublayer(border)
firstName.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: are your doing this in `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: @Dhiru, Yes, I call this function to the ViewDidLoad

Comment: see my answer and try , please let me know if this worked for you of not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extension

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension CALayer {

    func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {

        let border = CALayer()

        switch edge {
        case UIRectEdge.top:
            border.frame = CGRect.zero
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height - thickness, width: self.bounds.width, height: thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.left:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.bounds.height)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.right:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.bounds.height)
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor;

        self.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

and call them from controller

```
someTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 2)
```

UPDATE ANSWER : Create a new function and adding width as param

```
func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat, width: CGFloat) {

        let border = CALayer()

        switch edge {
        case UIRectEdge.top:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height - thickness, width: width, height: thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.left:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.bounds.height)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.right:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.bounds.height)
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor;

        self.addSublayer(border)
    }
```

After, you have to create a constraint for your TextField WIDTH
and call the extension by passing the constraint width, like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldConstraintWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
self.textField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 2, width: textFieldConstraintWidth.constant)
```

Comment: I did exactly what you write here but, I don't know why the border is not matched the width to the TextField :(

Comment: Works perfectly on my device. Thanks

Comment: I have update my answer, you can try the new function

Comment: So please mark it as Resolved :) ( check left the answer )

Comment: For those users who looking for the answer for the same problem, Check this function, and border maybe not working on the simulator, Try it on the Actual device, it would be worked.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
self.borderStyle = .none
self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

self.layer.masksToBounds = false
self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
```

Could add this as an extension to UIView.

```
extension UIView {
    func addBorder() {
        self.borderStyle = .none
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
       self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
   }
}
```

You can call it like so

```
firstName.addBorder()
```

Another way to do it without shadows is by adding a `UIView` of `1px` to the `TextField`

```
extension UIView {
    func addBorder() {
        let border = UIView.init()
        border.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        border.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        addSubview(border)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate
                          (NSLayoutConstraint.constraints
                          (withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[V]-0-|", 
                          options: [], 
                          metrics: nil, views: ["V" :border]))

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate
                          (NSLayoutConstraint.constraints
                          (withVisualFormat: "V:[V]-0-|", 
                          options: [], 
                          metrics: nil, views: ["V" : border]))

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate
                          (NSLayoutConstraint.constraints
                          (withVisualFormat: "V:|[V(1)]|", 
                          options: [], 
                          metrics: nil, views: ["V" : border]))`
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not a right approach I guess, as this makes the background White of the text field, What If I need the transparent background?

Comment: Another suggestion would be to add an extension to the UIView which add a UIView of width 1px into the textview and constraint it to the bottom. Simple solution. It will also scale will device orientation change since it's aligned using constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but lots of the UIView cause the UI slow. What do you think?

Comment: I've used that trick many times never had an issue with performance.

Comment: I am getting an error with the extension
Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'color' to the "border.color = .black"

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I think the last code is for Objective-C, right?

Comment: I had to split out the constraint code for it to format correctly on here. I've made a few more changes. The constraint code you will have to format when adding to ur project join it all into 1 line and it should compile. It's all Swift.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the UI Customization in **viewDidLayoutSubviews**(in `UIViewController class`) or in **drawRect** (in `UIView class`) instead of doing in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   //Do your UI Custumization stuff here 

let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(0.5)
border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(1).cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: firstName.frame.size.height - width, width:  firstName.frame.size.width, height: firstName.frame.size.height)

border.borderWidth = width
firstName.layer.addSublayer(border)
firstName.layer.masksToBounds = true
     }
```

Comment: it still not working for me, after override the viewDidLayoutSubviews class. 
http://imgur.com/S13pe0c

Answer (score 0):

I  think you are checking your code in simulator.Just run your code in a device. It works perfectly for me. No mistake with the above code.

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: Yes, it works perfect, I am wondering why it wouldn't work on the simulator?

Comment: simulator actually! - typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

Note: If UITextField object is created in Storyboard then set its Border Style property to None in Storyboard Attributes Inspector.

The following variable textField is an object of UITextField control in which the bottom border will be set.

Swift 4 code:

```
let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(2.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width: textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

border.borderWidth = width
textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` to diferents devices

I changed:

```
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height, width: textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)
```

to:

```
bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-50, height: 0.5)
```